# Problem with cache when enabling/disabling extensions

Tags: magento2, bug, cdn, caching

I have a problem with probably caching when I install/enable new extensions which should add custom tabs to the product edit page it never does even when I disable modules with custom tabs on the product edit page they never disappear. One extension support told me that it could be some kind of CDN problem but I couldn't figure out it. Could anyone help? thanks.[image: this is tabs which never disappear]

Comment: Hello, could be a problem with attribute sets, since it's possible that the fields are disabled in the set but the module is enabled, and for those attribute showing inside the product could be the same reason, you'll have to remove them from the set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is product attributes and its not depend on extension status.so,do below things for remove it from product form.

In Admin Panel(Backend) go to **Store -> Attributes -> Attribute Set -> Your attribute set**  eg. 'Default'.

and remove attributes which is no longer required -(which was created when you installed extension).

after save attribute set please run below command for indexing

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```